# How to make batch transaction in ethereum using web3.py

Tags: ether, python, web3.py, django

I want to make batch transaction in ethereum using the **web3.py.** I found 
`web3.createBatch()` in Web3.js, but i can not find it on web3.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batching is not supported in web3.py, as of v4.5.0. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/832) if you would like to be notified if/when it is added.